Which is the determining factor of performance in this query? The UPPER? The IN? The JSON ->> matching?
I am editing a Java stringtemplate4 file that's generating an SQL WHERE clause. Here's an example of the generated output:
where
campaign.id IN (
    select entity_id from campaign.measurement_metadata measurement
    where
    AND UPPER(measurement.measurement_partner) IN (
        'KOCHAVA'  , 'SPAA'  , 'IAS' 
    )
    AND (measurement.measurement_partner_metadata ->> 'enabled') =
        'true'
)
OR
flight.id IN (
    select entity_id from campaign.measurement_metadata measurement
    where
    AND UPPER(measurement.measurement_partner) IN (
        'KOCHAVA'  , 'SPAA'  , 'IAS' 
    )
    AND (measurement.measurement_partner_metadata ->> 'enabled') =
        'true'
)

Sorry about the inconsistent capitalization—that's just how the current code is. Anyway, the above works fine, but I'm bothered by the need to execute the same subquery twice. So I found a different way to write the condition:
where
EXISTS (
    select 1 from campaign.measurement_metadata measurement
    where measurement.entity_id IN (campaign.id, flight.id)
    AND UPPER(measurement.measurement_partner) IN (
        'KOCHAVA' 
    )
    AND (measurement.measurement_partner_metadata ->> 'enabled') =
        'true'
)

But I'm not sure how to reason about performance of these queries. Does the use of a function like UPPER render indexing ineffective? Is an index even possible to help an IN clause? Does matching in a JSON blob (->>) pretty much make any kind of indexing relatively ineffective? I didn't even know about that operator until yesterday.
Practically speaking, I just want to know if my new query is "not worse" than the original one. But I would love to learn the reasons why.
This database is managed via Flyway—here's the snippet that creates the table:
CREATE TABLE campaign.measurement_metadata
(
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    entity_id UUID NOT NULL,
    entity_type TEXT NOT NULL,
    measurement_partner TEXT NOT NULL,
    measurement_partner_metadata JSONB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (entity_id, entity_type, measurement_partner)
);

CREATE TRIGGER set_timestamp
    BEFORE UPDATE ON campaign.measurement_metadata
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE campaign.trigger_set_timestamp();

CREATE INDEX measurement_metadata_idx ON campaign.measurement_metadata (entity_id, entity_type, measurement_partner);


When using UPPER in your where condition, you have to do it in the index as well.

You can execute the subquery once, but use it twice, if you employ a CTE:
with entity_ids as (
    select entity_id from campaign.measurement_metadata measurement
    where UPPER(measurement.measurement_partner) IN ('KOCHAVA', 'SPAA', 'IAS')
    AND (measurement.measurement_partner_metadata ->> 'enabled') = 'true'
)

select ... 

where campaign.id in (select entity_id from entity_ids)
or flight.id in (select entity_id from entity_ids)

If you're building the query on demand, you'd add the CTE to the front of your base query.
